# Filter excel data with apache poi in java

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I want filter excel data by program. for example

```
   |  a  b  c  |
   |  1  x  x  |
   |  2  x  x  |
   .............
```

I want to filter column a where a values 1 and ignore other ,
I have google  a lot  and search docs in apache poi website but no effect, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The index of rows and columns are 0-based. Therefore if you want to scan column A, you have to use the index 0.

Further, if you want to iterate cells in a specific column, you have to iterate the rows and then get the cell from each row for the specific column number.

To filter cells by a given value, the following steps are necessary:

- check if the cell is not null
- check if the cell has the correct cell type (`CELL_TYPE_STRING` / `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`)
- check if the value contained by the cell is equivalent to the given filter value

## Iterate column A

An example for your specific problem. The code iterates all cells in the first column (column A) and prints out the corresponding coordinates.

```
final int firstRowNumber = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
final int lastRowNumber = sheet.getLastRowNum();

// Column A (index = 0)
// final int columnNumber = CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("A")
final int columnNumber = 0;

final int filterValue = 1;

// Iterate rows
for (int rowNumber = firstRowNumber; rowNumber < lastRowNumber; rowNumber++) {
    final Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);

    if (row != null) {
        final Cell cell = row.getCell(columnNumber);

        // Filter cells
        if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC && cell.getNumericCellValue() == filterValue) {
            System.out.println("Found cell with value " + filterValue + " at [" + rowNumber + "," + columnNumber + "]");
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use [CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(String)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertColStringToIndex%28java.lang.String%29) to turn the column label `A` into `0` to make it clearer

Comment: @Gagravarr thanks! By the way, is there also a function for the other way round? To generate the correct coordinate String from the row and column number?

Comment: Yup, just create a CellReference with [two ints](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#CellReference%28int,%20int%29), then call [formatAsString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#formatAsString%28%29) on it

Comment: I think the question was : Is there a way to filer on columns before parsing. Rows will parsed anyway. But in order to reduce number of iterations, is there a way to filter before iterating?

Answer (score 1):

It's a very general question, so I can only give a general answer:

I think you should start with [reading in the file](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) and [iterating over the Rows/Cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), then you can [query the Cell-Value](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) and go from there.

See the rest of the Guides at http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html and http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html for additional things that can be done.

Comment: tks,but I`ve read there before, but it`s too general, I asked this question  because need some example,  at last I do it myself and it cost me the whole day, anyhow, tks